# Why is my first eigenvector nearly constant and associated to a very high eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

The first eigenvector I obtain after decomposing an N x N symmetric correlation matrix (computed using a custom correlation measure) has very little variability in it.

It is also associated to a very high eigenvalue, usually ~50% higher than that of the second eigenvalue, e.g.: first eigenvalue = 1.9, second 1.3.

I've also noticed that the values of the first eigenvector are very closely related to the sum of my input matrix: Pearson's correlation = -0.80.

Second eigenvector's correlation is ~0.15, and the rest around 0.05.

What's the origin behind this (odd?) behavior of the first eigenvector?

Comment: "computed using a custom correlation measure" I am not sure it is possible to really help without knowing how the matrix is built.

Comment: I've reproduced this issue in a variety of ways. The most general of them being when using the Laplacian Eigenmaps algorithm (http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/projects/manifold/Papers/Laplacian.pdf). Essentially, it comes down to building a 1-C distance matrix (C being the Pearson's correlation), then using exp(-x) to construct the input matrix used for eigendecomposition. The Laplacian Eigenmaps algorithm also sparsifies this matrix using the the first K nearest neighbors, but I found this step to not be necessary to reproduce the constant first eigenvector.

Answer (score 1):

Your data must be very correlated and traversed by a main factor (think principal component)

Assuming your custom correl measure is 1 when applied to the same variable, the ratio of the top eigenvalue to N would typically correspond to the percentage of variance explained by the first principal factor...  Probably also close to the average correlation coefficient in your matrix...

Typical case would be financial correlation matrix, like stocks which are traversed by a main "market factor" (in PCA this would take a shape close to an equally-weighted portfolio).  See [Plerou et al](https://journals.aps.org/pre/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevE.65.066126) for an "early" paper on this topic (there are others)

Comment: Thanks for the article. My data does indeed have a lot of local and overlapping correlations (it's a simulated dataset), but no factors which traverse the entire structure. I still get this effect with random matrices as well. Could it be reflecting a certain bias by the correlation measure towards all variables? The correlation measure I am using indeed ranges between [-1 1], with 0 being decorrelation. I have also found this occurs in other cases where the [initial correlation matrix is altered](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/projects/manifold/Papers/Laplacian.pdf) prior to eigendecomposition.

Comment: Oh wow this looks like a pretty serious paper! I don't know much about random matrices but if you feel the simulated data is mutually independent then your correlation matrix should be close to the identity matrix, especially for large N... If it isn't, then I'd say the problem is with your data simulation procedure. As you probably know, if you multiply a data matrix of iid normals with the cholesky decomposition of a correlation matrix, you get a sample of correlated normals. So it's easy to unknowingly create a correlation structure by mixing independent variables together in calculations